# run nodejs script using the atom nodejs installation

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

Is it possible to run a nodejs script using the atom nodejs installation?

For instance I run a script using a command line such:

```
node r.js -o build.js
```

I would like to know if there is a way to do the same without having a separate nodejs installation.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "separate installation". Could you clarify a little ?

Comment: For what I understand atom is based on nodejs. So is it possible to run nodejs script using the atom nodejs if I dont have nodejs installed?

Comment: Sure atom is powered by nodejs, but I always thought it was the same as the one you use to run your script.

Comment: No atom have its own nodejs installation. For instance it's node v8.9.3 that is used by atom 1.33.1.

Comment: You're right. Atom is made with electron which has its own nodejs fork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atom is based on Electron which integrates it's own Node.js application. You can launch your script with the Node.js engine built into Atom by pointing directly at it.

For exemple on Linux, you can do:

```
$ /usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node r.js -o build.js
```